# Ruby app that instantly reflects changes in source files

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop

How can I design a ruby application in a way that everytime I save a .rb file it automatically starts behaving in "the new way"?

I mean, I'm writing a REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop) application and I would want it to work as if the source files are always reloaded everytime I change them.

Kind of in the way Rails or Unity(the game engine) does when you change and save the script files.

I've done done trial with Kernel.load, but it complains about redefined constants and spawns repeated threads.

Have anyone done something like that? How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You say you tried `Kernel.load`, but I see no code. We need to see what you've tried so answers can be tailored for your code. If we generate something it could be wildly different than the path you've taken.

Comment: I'm not really interested in code tailored for my application, but in generic guidelines for this kind of approach.

Comment: That's not what Stack Overflow is for. SO is for specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: @Vargas use `programmers.stackexchange.com` for that stype of questions

Answer (score 1):

Kernel.load should work for this. You can avoid redefining constants by determining if they are already defined

```
CONST = 2 unless defined?(CONST)
```

If you need to redefine constants then you could use a global variable such as `$const`

Both of these options will avoid the warnings also when reloading files_you should probably check to see if they have changed at all maybe by defining your own reload method.